# sed command - remove all commas from text between HTML tag

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, terminal

Please, someone help. I need to find and remove commas from specific HTML tags like < h3> and < h4> in command line but only from this tags.

Example:

```
...    
<h3>Sample header, with some, text with commas</h3>
<h4>Sample header, with some, text with commas</h4>

<p>Loreipsum sit amet, dolor...</p>
...
```

and I use:

```
sed "/<h3>/,/<\/h3>/s/,//g"
```

but this command remove commas from all code... I need only from < h3> and < h4> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
sed -e '/<*>/s/,/ /g' stack4.html
```

inside stack.html below strings are written

```
<h3>Sample header, with some, text</h3>
Hi, what's your namiue
<h3>Sample header, with some, text</h3>
<h3>Sample header, with some, text</h3>
hyt,ujt,yj
<h3>Sample header, with some, text</h3>
jkj<h3>Sample header, with some, text</h3>
```

o/p i got

```
<h3>Sample header  with some  text</h3>
Hi, what's your namiue
<h3>Sample header  with some  text</h3>
<h3>Sample header  with some  text</h3>
hyt,ujt,yj
<h3>Sample header  with some  text</h3>
jkj<h3>Sample header  with some  text</h3>
```

if you want to do only for h3 and h4 then below command may be help you

```
 sed -e '/<h[3-4]>/s/,/ /g' stack4.html
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately your command remove commas from all html tags. I only need to remove commas from <h3> and <h4> other tags must be intact.